# Spark Error reading csv file with spaces in the path/file name

Tags: apache-spark

I want to read a csv file using spark. The file's path has blank spaces. Spark is replacing the blank spaces with `%20`.

This is the code:

```
val tmpDF = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("multiLine", value = true).option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", delimiter).load(filename)

tmpDF.show(10)
```

So when the `tmpDF.show(10)` method is executed the following error is thrown:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: s3://{bucket_name}/all/Proposal%20and%20pre-approval/filen_name_20190826-215950.csv
```

It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running `REFRESH TABLE tableName` command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved."

I checked in s3 and the file does exist but the path has a regular space instead of `%20`.

Any idea how to handle this? I can't change the paths because they are produced by a component that I can't modify.

Comment: Try Using `s3n` schema

Comment: @SMaZ I got the following exception:No FileSystem for scheme: s3n. Exit Code is non-zero or 1, hence not updating the last modified date

Comment: Can you add detail log. Also, try accessing a file without any space. Seems like another issue.

Comment: instead of using .option("escape", "\"") with try this to read file .option("escape"," ") hope fully its solve your purpose. let me know if you face same issue

Answer (score 3):

This is the typical problem of url encoding. The URL coming from S3 is encoded with %20. However, spark incorrectly decodes that.

There had been two issues regarding this

1. https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23148
2. https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24320

The issues have been resolved in spark2.3 version. If you are using older version

You need to escape the file names after decode the url.