# How to read recursively files from folder in pyspark if spaces in path

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to read all images in local subfolder in pyspark :

> spark.read.format("image").option("recursiveFileLookup","true").load("./fruits-360-light/*")

Where `fruits-360-light` has subfolders like `Apple Golden`, `Apple Yellow`, `Pineapple Mini`, etc. When I execute this command, I have the following error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/path/to/script/fruits-360-light/Training/Pineapple%20Mini/170_100.jpg does not exist`

How am I supposed to read all files from this folder? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57719160/spark-error-reading-csv-file-with-spaces-in-the-path-file-name) it is stated (if I correctly understand) that this issue is supposed to be resolved since spark 2.3, but I have 3.0.2

Comment: This is working fine on Spark 3.0.1 version

Comment: Reading a subfolder without spaces in name is fine, indeed, but as soon as I change to a subfolder with space in name, it is not working.